# Bash: replace diacritical marks?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to replace all diacritical marks in bash to normal letters?

i.e.: ń -> n, Ą -> A, Ó -> O, Ć -> Ć, ę -> e etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit <<< 'ń -> n, Ą -> A, Ó -> O, Ć -> Ć, ę -> e'
n -> n, A -> A, O -> O, C -> C, e -> e

$ iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit <<< 'Kości zostały rzucone i żaden żywy człowien nie ujrzał już ćmy'
Kosci zostaly rzucone i zaden zywy czlowien nie ujrzal juz cmy
```

Comment: Of course. But it's available for any system you're likely to run into.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd have thought `tr` would be perfect for this:

`echo  ńę | tr abcdefghijklmnopqrstńĄÓĆę abcdefghijklmnopqrstnAOCę`

doesn't work for me though.

Comment: That's because tr does byte-wise replacement, not character-wise replacement.

Comment: Works for me, although the last character in either string is identical so the only the first letter is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found it:

```
echo "Kości zostały rzucone i żaden żywy człowien nie ujrzał już ćmy" | sed \
-e 's/ą/a/g' \
-e 's/ć/c/g' \
-e 's/ę/e/g' \
-e 's/ł/l/g' \
-e 's/ń/n/g' \
-e 's/ó/o/g' \
-e 's/ś/s/g' \
-e 's/[żź]/z/g' \
\
-e 's/Ą/Ą/g' \
-e 's/Ć/C/g' \
-e 's/Ę/E/g' \
-e 's/Ł/L/g' \
-e 's/Ń/N/g' \
-e 's/Ó/O/g' \
-e 's/Ś/S/g' \
-e 's/[ŻŹ]/Z/g' \
\
```

Comment: If you're going to do multiple single character replacements then you may want to look at the map operator (`y`) instead.

Comment: No, I will use yours solution :)

Answer (score -1):

You could run a sed, awk, Perl, Python, PHP, etc. program and capture the output into a Bash variable.